# Open a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm completely new to Eclipse/Java/Android programming, so this might sound like a dumb question, but I can't open the project I was working on last week... it's the "HelloWorld" project.

I'm very familiar with Visual Studio so I've been looking for something like a project file/solution or a way to open a directory in Eclipse, but I'm having no luck and am completely lost.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but get this: "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace."  If I'm in the right workspace, why can't I see the heirarchy or source files?

Comment: Oh... Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer... I just have to get used to Eclipse and not expect it to be VS2008.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, try using the Navigator view if you prefer seeing the directory structure and non-java files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try File->Import and then choose Existing Projects into Workspace and then select the directory with your HelloWorld project?

Comment: That works well, although it really is a log of effort just to open projects already in my workspace directory!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had it checked not to show closed projects.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse will look into the .project file in your project directory and see the original project name, which may be the same as another project. This can happen if you build a new project using some old code.

Comment: Thanks ... It worked for me.. I was facing the same problem while importing a project in Eclipse Helios